# Convert a list to int

Tags: python, string, list, integer

I have the following list:

```
lst=['(9971, 18847)',
 '(9971, 19188)',
 '(9972, 18282)',
 '(9977, 19201)',
 '(9989, 18635)',
 '(9993, 18225)',
 '(9996, 19099)',
 '(9997, 18178)',
 '(10000, 18266)']
```

I would like to convert each element in the list from str to int. How do I do that?

What I tried so far?

```
op=[]
for i in lst:
    new_lst=int(lst[i])
    op.append(new_lst)
```

I get the following error `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:`. How do I solve it?

Comment: Since it's not just one int in those strings, what do you expect the result to look like exactly?

Comment: `import ast; op = list(map(ast.literal_eval, lst))` should do…

Comment: I think the problem is upstream : how did you get this list ? You should try to get directly numbers instead of strings, so you don't need to use `eval()` after

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ast.literal_eval` with `list comprehenion`

```
import ast
[ast.literal_eval(l) for l in lst]

>>[(9971, 18847),
 (9971, 19188),
 (9972, 18282),
 (9977, 19201),
 (9989, 18635),
 (9993, 18225),
 (9996, 19099),
 (9997, 18178),
 (10000, 18266)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Without using `ast`:

```
[tuple(map(int, t.strip('()').split(', '))) for t in lst]

[(9971, 18847),
 (9971, 19188),
 (9972, 18282),
 (9977, 19201),
 (9989, 18635),
 (9993, 18225),
 (9996, 19099),
 (9997, 18178),
 (10000, 18266)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use tuple - unpacking. Try this -

```
mylist = []

for a in lst:
    x = a.split('(')
    for b in x:
        y = b.split(')')
    for c in y:
        z = c.split(',')
        if len(z) == 1:
            break
        else:

            for ele in z:
                mylist.append(int(ele))

print(mylist)
```

You will get a list of all the integers  instead of strings